# How to put If else statement in SQL where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `article` with fields `day` , `month` , `year` , `title`. So the `date` of article in the table would be `day-month-year` but has been stored in form of 3 different columns. I need to obtain titles of all those articles from the table which have been published between a given a `start_date` and an `end_date`.

Assume that `start_date` also is given in form of 3 variables - 
    `sday` , `smonth` , `syear`

And `end_date` as 3 variables - 
    `eday` , `emonth` , `eyear`

How can I write the mysql query for the above ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your fields are number.
So you can use the following code:

```
select * 
from article
where (year*10000+month*100+day) between (syear*10000+smonth*100+sday) and (eyear*10000+emonth*100+eday)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way seems to convert the years, months and days to real dates.  Then the database can do the hard work.  You can convert the components to a date like:

```
cast('2014-04-01' as datetime)
```

In a query, this would look like:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   cast(concat(`year`, '-', `month`, '-', `day`) as datetime)
        <
        cast(concat(2014, '-', 4, '-', 30) as datetime)
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ecb/8/0)

Answer (score 1):

You could just compare each element of the date at a time:

```
SELECT * FROM article
       WHERE (year>syear OR 
              (year=syear AND (month>smonth OR 
                               (month=smonth AND day>=sday)))) AND
             (year<eyear OR
              (year=eyear AND (month<emonth OR
                               (month=emonth AND day<=eday))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for mysql, here is the final sql :

```
select * from article 
where  STR_TO_DATE(concat(day,',',month,',',year),'%d,%m,%Y') 
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(concat(@sday,',',@smonth,',',@syear),'%d,%m,%Y')
       AND STR_TO_DATE(concat(@eday,',',@emonth,',',@eyear),'%d,%m,%Y');
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a053/11) demo

Answer (score 0):

Join the three strings together, then use the string to date function of mysql to get the date to compare:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') 
....
```

Where "yourdatefield" is a concatenation of your date parts.